# Check if application running or test running

Tags: asp.net-core, nunit, kestrel-http-server

I want to port the code below to core. But is there anyway to check code is running (ex: on kestrel) or running on test (ex : on NUnit)

```
        if (HostingEnvironment.IsHosted)
        {
            //hosted
            return HostingEnvironment.MapPath(path);
        }

        //not hosted. For example, run in unit tests
        var baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        path = path.Replace("~/", "").TrimStart('/').Replace('/', '\\');
        return Path.Combine(baseDirectory, path);
```

I tried to do this
_hostingEnvirontment is IHostingEnvironment

```
        if (I MUST CHECK IS HOSTED OR NOT)
        {
            //hosted
            return _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath + path;
        }

        //not hosted. For example, run in unit tests
        var baseDirectory = AppContext.BaseDirectory;
        path = path.Replace("~/", "").TrimStart('/').Replace('/', '\\');
        return Path.Combine(baseDirectory, path);
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than have the code you are testing "know" whether it is running live or under a test framework, it's better to inject those things that need to be changed in the test environment. This makes your application generally more testable and avoids a lot of the risks inherent in having the sut know about the test framework.

Consider creating a TestHostingEnvironment that implements IHostingEnvironment and providing it to the SUT when running tests.

Comment: This is based framework, I am trying to port it with minimum changes. Anyway your idea comes first in mind and the best way to do this. But not answer my question.